# Template C++: How to access iterator value for both std::map and std::set?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl, set

I have a specific search function. Because it's used on both `std::set` and `std::map`, it was duplicated in our code (not using template).

I have to maintain those two functions, and I'd like to move them to a single function using a template (and then have only one search preocedure to maintain).

I can't find how to convert an iterator to the container's `value_type`. For `std::set`, you just need to dereference the iterator (*iter), but for `std::map`, you need to access the second item of the iterator (which is a pair) `iter->second`.

Here is an isolated example:

```
template <class Container, class Object> bool MyFindFunction( const Container& container, Object& found )
{
    Container::const_iterator iter = container.begin();
    // do my special search procedure here
    // note that this code also needs to access the iterator's value...

    if ( iter != container.end() )
    {
        found = *iter; // this works for set, but not for map
        found = iter->second; // this works for map, but not for set
        // HOW TO MAKE IT WORK FOR BOTH??
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::set<double> mySet;
    std::map<int,double> myMap;
    double found = 0;

    MyFindFunction( mySet, found );
    MyFindFunction( myMap, found );
}
```

Note that the special search procedure also needs to access the `value_type` (or `mapped_type` for maps), so, moving this procedure to a template function and having a `MyFindFunctionInMap` and `MyFindFunctionInSet` function handling iterator to value conversion after calling the search procedure function won't help.

PS: Sorry, I'm using C++98..

Comment: Just create an `access` function using the templated iterator and implement it for map/set iterator. So you dont have the complete function implementedtwice, just the problematic access

Comment: Pedantic point: the `value_type` of a `std::map<A, B>` is `std::pair<const A, B>`, which is exactly what dereferencing an iterator gives you. The type you're looking for is `mapped_type`.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for mapped_type, which is not defined for sets...this one only has value_type....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `template function overload` to distinguish these cases:

```
template <typename V>
inline V get_value(const V& v) { return v; }
template <typename K, typename V>
inline V get_value(const std::pair<K, V>& p) { return p.second; }
```

and then

```
found = get_value(*iter);
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/abW8Wx)

Comment: I like that, but it does not compile (I'm using VS2010). Apparently the map version function is not used by the compiler. Would there by a way to pass the get_value function to be used as a parameter?

Comment: @jpo38 My fault. I've updated my answer, pls check again.

Comment: It works great and is really a nice and easy way to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to build a `set`-like iterator from the `map`-like iterator.

Create an internal template function parameterized by a `set`-like iterator  and only taking iterators, not the container, as arguments. Dispatch to this function either the original iterator or the transformed iterator.

---

**Edit** If you cannot use boost, build some functor to access your stuff:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


template<class Key, class Value>
struct access_key
{
    template<class Ref>
    const Key &operator()(const Ref &v) const
    {
        return v.first;
    }
};

template<class Key>
struct access_key<Key, Key>
{
    template<class Ref>
    const Key &operator()(const Ref &v) const
    {
        return v;
    }
};


template<class Container>
void fn(Container t)
{
    access_key<typename Container::key_type, typename Container::value_type> a;
    cout << a(*t.begin()) << endl;
}


int main()
{
    set<int> s;
    s.insert(1);

    map<int, int> m;
    m[1] = 1;

    fn(s);
    fn(m);

    return 0;
}
```

This accessor relies on the key type and value type being distinct/same for map/set.

Comment: @jpo38 See update. In the future, you might want to state restrictions in your question, BTW.

Comment: Sorry about that. access_key operator returns v.first, should it be v.second? Could you provide an example about how to use this access_key struct?

Comment: This gives access to the key, not the value, right? I adapted to value (changed `v.first` to `v.second` and return value from `Key` to `Value` but it does not work)

Comment: @jpos38 Just change `first` to `second`. The rest stays the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80651/discussion-between-jpo38-and-ami-tavory).

Answer (score -2):

One practical solution can be using extra boolean parameter to figure out whether container is map or not:

```
template <class Container, class Object> bool MyFindFunction( const Container& container, Object& found, bool isMap ){
   ..
   if(!isMap){
      found = *iter; // this works for set, but not for map
   }
   else{
      found = iter->second; // this works for map, but not for set
   }
..
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Even if only used with isMap set to true, compiler complains `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'double'`